# GNU Screen: Visual indication of copy mode

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

When I enable copy mode in a window, I see "Copy mode ..." in the bottom line of the terminal. I configure screen to show the list of windows on the bottom. Now, when I switch to another window and then back to the first window, the notification that I am in copy mode is gone. (And I wonder why a command takes so long, until I press a key, and realize I'm in copy mode.)

So my question is: is there a "permanent" visual indication that a given session is in copy mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In git version, new caption string `P` added.

> sets %? to true if the current region is in copy/paste mode

I'm using this in following setting.

```
caption always '%?%F%{= gW}%:%{= Kk}%?%2n%f%07=%t%?%P *** copy/paste mode ***%:%?%='
```

When you move into copy-mode, string `*** copy/paste mode ***` displayed in window caption.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your reply. I tried the master branch of http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/ , but the caption you showed didn't work for me. Can you please point me to the correct repository/branch?

Comment: I'm using the master of branch(450e8f3). and simply `git clone && cd screen/src && ./autogen.sh && configure && make && make install`. The following screenshots are an example of my copy-mode caption that I use. [screenshot1](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-SnEhTXB5QqI/TSpSUlBzDnI/AAAAAAAAAQk/PD_HKZRVaJI/s754/screen_variables.png) [screenshot2](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-SOAJmAuZDpw/TvS3KkIa43I/AAAAAAAAAwA/d2jozf1ajrQ/s800/screen_caption_copy.png)

Comment: oh... don't forget gnu screen. :)

Comment: `%P` seems to work fine with `caption`, but not with `hardstatus`. Maybe a bug?